# My vba code to split text and numbers doesnt work

Tags: vba

I have written this code to split text and number in excel but whenever I run it... it doesn't work

```
  Public Function Strip(ByVal x As String, LeaveNums As Boolean) As Variant
   Dim y As String, z As String, n As Long
   For n = 1 To Len(x)
   y = Mid(x, n, 1)
   If LeaveNums = False Then
       If y Like "[A-Za-z ]" Then z = z & y 'False keeps Letters and spaces only
   Else
       If y Like "[0-9. ]" Then z = z & y   'True keeps Numbers and decimal points
   End If
   Next n
Strip = Trim(z)
End Function
```

Comment: Your code works for me. Can you explain what doesn't work? Do you get an error? on which line?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a descriptive error message, please include the actual error message (if any) in your question, otherwise describe the problem. Do you get unexpected results? As Pierre44 mentioned already, your function works on our end.

Comment: @Pierre44 it shows choose macro pop up

Comment: How do you call your function? As a UDF? From within another subroutine? From the immediate window? You cannot call it from the IDE with F5 because it expects parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You've written (copied?) a `Function`, not a subroutine. Functions are commonly used for repeated processes, and return (if written properly) values. So, you call a function from within a subroutine and then do something with the value the function returned. The function does something with the `x` and `LeaveNums` parameters, just like formulae do.
In fact, you can write Functions and use these as formulae in your Excel worksheets.

You can call this Function as follows (note, this is an example)

```
Sub Usefunction()

rslt = Strip("test this 1.01", True)

MsgBox rslt

End Sub
```

This will return "test this". If you set the boolean to `False`, the function returns "1.01" instead.